# How to write a shell script to compare values numerically?

Tags: shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I want the file fig.txt read in a shell script like here the number is 8 so if the number/value is less  and equal to the value 5000 it will alert via mail that lock file overflow and if not it will alert lock file is ok.

```
pkity:/tech/cmd/dump# cat lngtrans2.out

Lock table entries in use:         8 of 8000

Lock table high water mark:        12

Shared memory allocated:           1788 K (1 segments. The last segment was not locked in memory)

pkity:/tech/cmd/dump#  grep "Lock table entries" lngtrans2.out | cut -d " " -f 14 > fig.txt

pkity:/tech/cmd/dump# cat fig.txt

8

pkity:/tech/cmd/dump#
```

Comment: Please format your question, and give it a meaningful title. Some references https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Please always use useful titles. Stack Overflow is not a chatroom or a forum.

Comment: @halfer I apologize I am new in this forum. I will sure do next time :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can start with something like this.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

locked=$(grep "Lock table entries" lngtrans2.out | cut -d " " -f 14)

if [ "${locked}" -le 5000 ]; then
    mail -s "Lock file overflow" someone@somewhere.com << EOF
Lock table entries in use critical: ${locked}
EOF
fi
```